# React - Jumpy animation when item leaves DOM

Tags: animation, reactjs

I'm using `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` on a list of tags, so when one is removed by the user, it fades out. I noticed a bit of jumpiness going on, so I slowed the animation transition duration to see what was going on.

[image]

The tags shift in a weird way, and due to the widths being different, it looks a bit jarring when it disappears. Is this just how React animations work, or am I doing something wrong?

Here's another example at full speed (.3s).

[image]

Code below:

```
let ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

TagList = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'TagList',

  propTypes: {
    tags: React.PropTypes.array,
    onTagClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },

  render() {
    let tags;

    if (!this.props.tags) {
      return false;
    }

    tags = this.props.tags.map((tag, i) => {
      return <Tag key={i}
                  index={i}
                  onTagClick={this.props.onTagClick}>{tag}</Tag>
    });

    return (
      <div className="tag-list">
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="tag">
          {tags}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

Tag = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Tag',

  propTypes: {
    onTagClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <span className="tag"
            onClick={this.props.onTagClick.bind(null, this.props.index)}>
        <span className="tag-name">{this.props.children}</span>
      </span>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you setup a demo of your about output? JSfiddle.net or http://plunkr.co ?

Comment: @ManojKumar I added some code to the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React uses the `key` of the added/removed element to determine which DOM node to animate. You're using the array index of the tag for the key, but that's not stable across renders.

For example, if you have the array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and you remove the item at index 2, you're left with

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

However, to React, it looks like now `4` is at index 2; the `key` that will be removed is `4`, since there are now only four items in the array. That's why, in the first example, the tag you clicked on was *removed*, but the DOM node that was faded out was for the *last* item in the array.

The solution is to use a key that doesn't change for each individual tag (e.g. an ID, etc., even if you just generate unique IDs on the client.)